# Laravel 5.3 : txt or csv file throws an exception (getimagesize(): Read error!)

Tags: laravel

I have used following code to validate the image file. I want to upload image file only.
However when user upload the txt or csv file it throws an exception (getimagesize(): Read error!).
Below is the validation code.

```
$rules = [ 'mobile_image'=>'mimes:jpg,jpeg,gif,png|dimensions:width=710,height=400', 'web_image'=>'mimes:jpg,jpeg,gif,png|dimensions:width=1182,height=300', ]; 
$validator = Validator::make($validateData, $rules); 
if($validator->fails()){ 
}
```

I have checked in Laravel validation file.
They have used getimagesize for all file uploads.
Is there any other validation rule for txt or csv file ?
Is there any way to overwrite the validator class with custom rules ?

Answer (score 0):

You're using `dimensions` rule, so Laravel executes `getimagesize()` to get image dimensions. If you want to upload text files, change `mimes` and remove `dimensions` rule.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation

Comment: No, I don't want to upload text file. I want to upload image file. However in validation it throws error when someone try to upload txt file

Comment: Yes, I understood the getimagesize() issue and already mentioned in my question. 
I have to validate image with dimension as well. However if user tries to upload the txt file then it throws exception (which I have currently handled in try catch block).
I want to handle this error with some custom Laravel validation . Is there any way to do so ?

Answer (score 0):

Try below example code:

```
$validator = Validator::make($validateData,[
    'mobile_image'=>'mimes:jpg,jpeg,gif,png|dimensions:width=710,height=400',
    'web_image'=>'mimes:jpg,jpeg,gif,png|dimensions:width=1182,height=300',
])->validate();
```

**UPDATE**
You can try below snippet at own your risk:

```
$image_size = @getimagesize( $image_url );
if($image_size === false){
    //Handle error message
}
else {
    $validator = Validator::make($validateData,[
        'mobile_image'=>'mimes:jpg,jpeg,gif,png|dimensions:width=710,height=400',
        'web_image'=>'mimes:jpg,jpeg,gif,png|dimensions:width=1182,height=300',
    ])->validate();
}
```

Hope this will solved your issue.

Comment: I have already handled it with try catch block. I want some extension for Laravel.

Comment: You can try [Image Validator Rules For Laravel 5](https://github.com/cviebrock/image-validator) laravel extension